# Using the value that any_of finds to use in a return outside lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

A working piece of code:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator it = std::find_if(intersections.begin(), intersections.end(), [&](const double i) {return i >= 0;});
if (it != intersections.end())
    return rayOrigin + *(it) * rayDirection);
```

But I would like to use something like this

Is there a way to capture the *i* in a clean way (not using a temp variable), that the any_of finds here to use it in the return statement

```
if (std::any_of(intersections.begin(), intersections.end(), [&](const double i) {return i >= 0;}))
    return rayOrigin + i * rayDirection);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write a range-based searcher that returns an object which can be `*` dereferenced (maybe more than once) to get the found thing, or evaluated in a `bool` context to determine if it was found.

In my experience this makes code cleaner, and makes the common case of "I want to know if it is there" simpler, yet permits you to get at the item tersely:

```
template<class Range, class F>
auto linear_search_if( Range&& r, F&& f )
// remove next line in C++14, it removes ADL `begin` capability:
-> typename std::iterator_traits<decltype( std::begin(r) )>::value_type*
// reproducing ADL begin in C++11 is a pain, so just use the above line
{
  using std::begin;  using std::end;
  using iterator = decltype(begin(r));
  using T = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type;
  using R = T*; // in C++17 I prefer std::optional<iterator>;
  iterator it = std::find_if( begin(r), end(r), std::forward<F>(f) );
  if (it != end(r))
    return R(std::addressof(*it)); // return R(it); in C++17
  else
    return R(nullptr); // return R{}; in C++17
}

if (auto pi = linear_search_if( intersections, [&](auto i){return i>=0;})
  return rayOrigin + *pi * rayDirection; // **pi in C++17
```

Yes, you do a `*pi` instead of just an `i`.

Comment: a bit more explanations maybe..? "you prefer"?

Comment: @Ven Yes, in C++17, I personally would prefer to return an `optional<iterator>` instead of a `T*` in such a function?  I could go on about why I'd prefer it, but that is tangental to the solution.

Comment: if it is, why include it here?

Comment: @Ven When I write code for others to learn from, I try to make it worth emulating?  And in C++17, the solution with optional is a better one.  C++17 is basically here, I don't want to encourage people to use `T*` when `optional<iterator>` would be better.  By mentioning it as a better option, if they have a C++17 compiler, they might emulate that and produce *better* code than if I didn't mention it.

Comment: If you're just gonna say "this solution is the Best Solution™" but not explain why, then yeah I'm going to say "don't"

Comment: @Ven And that is ok.  You don't have to do it.  I won't make you.  I didn't say it was the Best Solution.  I said I personally would prefer it.  Others, when exposed to it, have also liked it, but that is just anecdotal.  It is up to you to determine if you agree.  If I took each line of code and explained everything about why I wrote it, I'd be writing chapters of books and not SO answers.  Want to learn about `using std::begin` line?  The `iterator traits` line?  The use of `find_if`?  Why `addressof`?  All of these *have reasons*, and I am not going to go into them *every time* I use them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the current ways of `find_if` and `any_of` are slightly annoying. @Yakk's solution works by writing a wrapper around `std::find_if` that returns a `std::optional<int>` to both test for success and conditionally extract the result. This is certainly a way forward for a next version of the STL.

However, in C++17, you can [**move initializers into selection statements**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html) which eliminates most of the pain already:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto const v = std::vector<int> { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
    auto const pred = [&](const int i) { return i >= 0; };

    if (auto const it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), pred); it != v.end())
        std::cout << *it << '\n';      
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5YW0iBX4XHONn7jN) using a recent Clang in c++1z mode.